# Configuration to do the spring dependency injection in action class in struts 2?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, struts2

i have legacy j2ee project which is using struts 2 with spring. Now  when i put debugger in first method call in action
class, i find all instance variables dependecies are injected automatically. i mean where do we configure dependency 
injection for  action class in struts? i explored the `web.xml` too , i do not find any related stuff?

Comment: whats wrong with this question to attract negative vote after 3 years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your struts configuration (struts.xml) contain an element like this?:

```
<constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory" />
```

Read more at http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/spring-plugin.html

Comment: as per struts site: it should be like
<constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring">
is it making any difference?
Ref: http://struts.apache.org/plugins/spring/

Answer (score 1):

If Spring is beiing used to inject the Dependencies for struts2 which includes results/actions etc.that means your code must be using [Struts2-Spring plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/spring-plugin.html).Struts2 by default use its own Object factor to create instances of Action classes/ Results and Interceptors etc.
In order to use Spring one need to tell Struts2 about which object creation factory to be used.for that we need to define the following entry in to either struts.xml file or struts.properties file

### struts.xml

```
<struts>
  <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory" />
  ... 
</struts>
```

### struts.properties

```
struts.objectFactory = org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory
```

I belive that in your `web.xml` you will find an entry to Spring's `ContextLoaderListener` which will load the `applicationContext` xml file from the class path.

when uusing Spring the action will be create by spring in its xml file and in the action configuration file the bean reference is being used in place of Action Class name.

So all you need to check `applicationContext.xml` in your Project where Action will be initiated as a `prototype` beans and those bean references being used in `struts.xml` file to defining your Struts2 Action class

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it. Sorry for double-post :)

Comment: Hi umesh , i dont see any entry of org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory in my complete project.Though i see the StrutsSpringObjectFactory2.2.3.1 jar file in my repository. Not getting where struts  is configured to use this factory?

Comment: @MSach do you have struts2-spring-plugin-2.2.3.1 in your project depedencies?

Comment: Yes Umesh, i can see below entry in my pom.xml   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
    </dependency>

Comment: have you cross checked your struts.xml file or property file for ObjectFactory entry??

Comment: @MSach: if you are not using multiple object factories, i bekive you need not to have the entry in your struts.xml file.All you need to have jar in the classpath.Just read the plugin page for details

Comment: Yes i have double checked.I dont find StrutsSpringObjectFactory 
 name in complete project. Thogh in jar is incuded as dependency in pom file. One more information in web.xml i can see these two filters StrutsPrepareFilter and StrutsExecuteFilter.Not sure how will it affect?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6900/discussion-between-umesh-awasthi-and-m-sach)

Comment: @MSach: those entry will not be in web.xml but might be in struts.xml or struts.properties file both should be in classpath.The one you have mentioned is Struts Filter Dispatcher entry point for struts2 framework